# Would born-blind people be able to make sense of shapes if they were healed?

Tags: neurology

[Molyneux's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molyneux%27s_Problem) was published in Locke's [An Essay Concerning Human Understanding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_Concerning_Human_Understanding) in 1690.

It was a thought experiment which essentially asked whether a person who was born blind, and could feel the difference between shapes and sizes, would be able to recognise them by sight if they were made to see.

Locke and Molyneux thought the answer was no.

In the intervening 300 years, has there been any empirical evidence to support their belief?

Comment: Please add references to the claim. Anyway, why would the person understand color but not shapes? ;) Finally, I think this would be better answered on [Biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) or possibly [Cognitive Sciences SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @nico, I added references.

Comment: @Oddthinking I thought all claims [need to be current](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/do-claims-need-to-be-current), if so is there any evidence people still think this now? Otherwise maybe it should go to Biology.SE or Philosophy.SE ?

Comment: @Oddthinking thanks for the edit. There is a minor error though, we are talking about `...a person who...` and at the end of the paragraph we find `...if they were made to see`. My English skills aren't that awesome to correct it, so I tell you instead

Comment: @Sonny, yes, it was still notable until recently, but it is tricky finding a reference that doesn't then go on to immediately state the solution. [e.g.](http://m.medicalxpress.com/news/2011-04-scientists-centuries-old-debate-perception.html) '“Ever since then [300 years ago], this has been one of the foremost questions in the philosophy of mind,” says Pawan Sinha, professor in MIT’s Department of Brain and Cognitive Sciences (BCS).'

Comment: @Oddthinking OK thanks. I hadn't heard of it but it makes for interesting reading.

Comment: @ajax333221: Use of [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) to avoid "his or her" isn't universally accepted by prescriptivists, but [isn't "an error"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is correct: they would have difficulty making out shapes.

David Hubel and Torsten Wiesel did a series of experiments in the sixties in which they showed that there is a critical period shortly after birth during which the brain needs input from the eye in order to become organized in such a manner that a person can see. They got the Nobel Prize for Physiology or Medicine for this in [1981](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/medicine/laureates/1981/presentation-speech.html).

From the Nobel Prize website:

> Hubel and Wiesel in their investigations were also able to show that
>   the ability of the cortical cells to interpret the code of the impulse
>   message from the retina develops early during a period directly after
>   birth. A prerequisite for this development to take place is that the
>   eye is subjected to visual experiences. **If during this period one eye
>   is sutured even for a few days, this can result in permanently
>   impaired vision** because the capacity of the brain to interpret the
>   picture has not developed normally.

A more detailed description of these experiments can be found [here](http://jn.physiology.org/content/early/2008/01/23/jn.00061.2008.full.pdf)

As to what kind of sensations a previously blind person would have, if their eyes suddenly began to work, I don't know. The cells that Hubel and Wiesel describe, encode information about orientation. Perhaps it is true that seeing color would be possible.

Comment: This is also what causes [Amblyopia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblyopia).